# Get halfedge from edge in cgal

Tags: cgal

what I need to do is given a `edge_iterator` and get a `halfedge_handle`,I checked the cgal document and feel confused

here is my code

```
for(Edge_iterator ei = mesh.edges_begin();
ei != mesh.edges_end(); ei++){
   // get the halfedge handle
 }
```

I know this looks like a silly question, just can't find the answer, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An edge is simply one of the two opposite halfedges.
You can simply write

```
  Halfedge_handle h = ei;
```